# How to pass item value to oracle function in oracle application express?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have item in oracle apex

```
P12_MOBILE_NUMBER
```

on form load I am fetching data using fetch row from and set to different items. Once mobile number set to item P12_MOBILE_NUMBER, I want to pass its item value to oracle function and function returned value set to P12_MOBILE_NUMBER again .

I can call my function like

```
Select stars(mobile_number)as mobile_number from dual;
```

Please help me out how can I do that , I am using application express 18.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **Page Load** dynamic action:

- set its True action to "Execute PL/SQL Code"
- that code would be

  ```
  :P12_MOBILE_NUMBER := stars(:P12_MOBILE_NUMBER);
  ```
- Items to submit: `P12_MOBILE_NUMBER`
- Items to return: `P12_MOBILE_NUMBER`

Run the page; automatic row fetch will fetch row value, and page load dynamic action will modify the mobile number (based on what your function actually does).

Comment: just like a boss

Comment: can you please share your email adress and skypeid if you don't mind

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to keep that info private. But I'll be glad to assist if you have any questions and post them here (and if I know the answer, of course).